# SQLITE - Performing Insertions inside triggers

Tags: sqlite, triggers, sql-insert

I'm trying to create a trigger that auto inserts tuples into a relation when a tuple is added in some other relation.

This is the code I have:

```sql
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS AdicionaAmigos; 

CREATE TRIGGER AdicionaAmigos 
AFTER INSERT ON Estudante 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO Amizade
    VALUES
    (
        SELECT New.ID, Estudante.ID 
        FROM Estudante 
        WHERE New.curso = Estudante.curso AND New.ID <> Estudante.ID
    );
    INSERT INTO Amizade
    VALUES
    (
        SELECT Estudante.ID, New.ID 
        FROM Estudante 
        WHERE New.curso = Estudante.curso AND New.ID <> Estudante.ID
    );
END;
```

This is the error I'm receiving:

```
Error: near line 101: near "SELECT": syntax error
```

line 101 = CREATE TRIGGER AdicionaAmigos

SQLITE Version: 3.17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a syntax error in your `INSERT INTO` statements.
You must drop the `VALUES` clause and keep `INSERT INTO...SELECT...`:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS AdicionaAmigos; 

CREATE TRIGGER AdicionaAmigos 
AFTER INSERT ON Estudante 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO Amizade
        SELECT New.ID, Estudante.ID 
        FROM Estudante 
        WHERE New.curso = Estudante.curso AND New.ID <> Estudante.ID;
    INSERT INTO Amizade
        SELECT Estudante.ID, New.ID 
        FROM Estudante 
        WHERE New.curso = Estudante.curso AND New.ID <> Estudante.ID;
END;
```

You can find more about the `INSERT INTO` syntax [here](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-insert/).
Also, the separate `INSERT INTO` statements can be combined in 1 with `UNION ALL`:

```
INSERT INTO Amizade
    SELECT New.ID, Estudante.ID 
    FROM Estudante 
    WHERE New.curso = Estudante.curso AND New.ID <> Estudante.ID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Estudante.ID, New.ID 
    FROM Estudante 
    WHERE New.curso = Estudante.curso AND New.ID <> Estudante.ID;
```